# “NOT AUTHENTICATED” warning trying to install rdesktop on almost-fresh Mint 16 install

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, authentication, rdesktop

Linux Mint 16 (Ubuntu-based) 32-bit running on a netbook. Installed Wine and Skype, and all updates. Went to install `rdesktop` (typed `rdesktop` in the gnome menu search, chose 'install `rdesktop`'), and I get a screen similar to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXCf.png), except that under the heading "NOT AUTHENTICATED," when I click the plus, there's just one blank line, no actual package names. The summary says 10 will be held back, 1 will be installed. I assume the 1 is `rdesktop`, so what's this blank line and warning all about? Will I fall victim to some MitM attack if I click "apply"?

Comment: A screen similar so which one?

Comment: @AndreasWiese, updated with link, thanks for calling that to my attention.  Sorry, I was reposting a question from a botched migration from superuser to askubuntu, which I didn't realize didn't include ubuntu-based distros like mint.  I couldn't click 'edit' anymore and copied the rendered text, which didn't include the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose cancel, and the second time I tried this, I didn't see this dialog at all.  I'm not sure what change might have occurred to account for the difference, but hopefully it was nothing to worry about in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, but had to click refresh on the update manager in order to get passed the error.